# Switched my Mac to having photos in iCloud - cannot see them on my iPhone

Tags: iphone, icloud, photos

I have a 200+ GB photo library with Photos on my Macbook.  I have synchronized these to my iPhone for many years, and used Photostream to have the photos I take automatically end up in my photo library on my Macbook.  This has worked well, but it has outgrown the harddisk on my Mac.

After taking a backup of my photos, I bought more space and enabled iCloud on the Macbook last week (immediately disabling Photostream which I did not like, but that is another story), and I can verify that it looks like on icloud.com that my whole library has been copied to the cloud.  So far so good.  (Except now some of my photos in my photo library are duplicated apparently)

Now I want to enable my iPhone 8 (fully updated) to utilize this.  It took a while to figure out that I needed to undo the Finder synchronization of photos in order to turn iCloud on on the iPhone, but now the iCloud slider stays at "enabled" and everything looks as I would expect it too.

Except that the photos do not show in the Photos app!  I can see all those present in the camera roll being presented as Photos, but none of those in iCloud.  For all practical purposes it looks like they are not known to Photos.

Have I missed something?  Is there a known problem with those coming from an older solution? Are they somewhere else I didn't think of to look?

Comment: Which of the two options is selected in Photos option within iCloud  on the iPhone: “Optimize ... “ or “Download ...”? How long ago did you enable iCloud photos on your iPhone?

Comment: Apparently not long enough.  I've had a closer look and at the very bottom of the Photos tab it says "Synchronizing".  I would have guessed that stuff showed up immediately, but it may have to wait until that message goes away.